# How hive find given decimal value is incorrect to defined decimal type and return NULL

Tags: java, hive, decimal

On Hive shell when I fire query 
**select cast(1234.0 as decimal(7,6))** it return NULL.
also 1234.0 with decimal(7,5),decimal(7,4) is invalid and Hive return NULL. But with Decimal(7,0),Decimal(7,1),Decimal(7,2),Decimal(7,3) it worked. Can any body tell me how Hive works with decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Decimal(magnitude,scale)
```

means a decimal with *magnitude* total significant digits, of which *scale* are to the right of the decimal point.  So `Decimal(7,3)` can contain a number of up to 7 significant digits, of which 3 are to the right of the decimal (i.e. `mmmm.sss`) while `Decimal(7,4)` still has 7 total digits but 4 are to the right of the decimal point, leaving only three for the integer part (`mmm.ssss`).

This latter format is not capable of representing the number `1234.0` as it has too many digits to the *left* of the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jim now I am able to understand it. so issue is left digit cant be greater then (precision - scale). Is this also apply to scale . Liek if scale is 2 and digits right side are 3

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tried it and found right side can have less digits then scale but left side can't have digits more then (precision-scale)

Comment: Yes. Losing trailing decimal places is minor, but losing data left of the decimal point is unacceptable.